# Why doesn't Twitter's typeahead.js work with my JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

### Update:

It is possible that this is an encoding issue, but I'm not quite sure how to figure it out or solve it. If I open `nba2.json` in Sublime Text 3, go to the console and type `view.encoding()` I get `Undefined` although `UTF-8` is displayed in the status bar (to display the encoding in ST3's status bar, you have to add `"show_encoding": true` to your user preferences).

Doing the same with `ktb.json` I get `UTF-8` on the console as well as in the status bar.

---

### Original Post:

Good day!

I'm trying to integrate Twitter's [typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) into my web application. I followed the [examples](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) and everything went well.

I then tried to use my own data source, building upon [these](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#prefetch) [two](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#multiple-datasets) examples.

I modified these examples in a way I thought should work (I'll get to my code in a bit), but that apparently didn't work out. Hence Im asking for your help.

I started with this bit of code:

```js
var nbaTeams = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: '../testData/nba.json'
});

nbaTeams.initialize();

$('#multiple-datasets .typeahead').typeahead({
    highlight: true
},
{
    name: 'nba-teams',
    displayKey: 'team',
    source: nbaTeams.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        header: '<h3 class="league-name">NBA Teams</h3>'
    }
});
```

Note that I took the `nba.json` file from [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/gh-pages/data/nba.json).

This attempt worked perfectly fine as you can see in this picture:

[image]

I then modified the `nba.json` file to look like this (I shortened the list for readability):

```js
[
  {
    "team": "Boston Celtics",
    "test": "one"
  },
  {
    "team": "Dallas Mavericks",
    "test": "two"
  },
  {
    "team": "Brooklyn Nets",
    "test": "three"
  },
  {
    "team": "Houston Rockets",
    "test": "four"
  }
]
```

I made these changes because the examples only handled JavaScript objects with only one property, but the objects I intend to use are made up of many properties (as you will see in a second).

I changed the code from above accordingly:

```js
var nbaTeams = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: '../testData/nba2.json'
});

nbaTeams.initialize();

$('#multiple-datasets .typeahead').typeahead({
    highlight: true
},
{
    name: 'nba-teams',
    displayKey: 'test',
    source: nbaTeams.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        header: '<h3 class="league-name">NBA Teams</h3>'
    }
});
```

As you can see, I changed the value of `displayKey` to `test` in order the get the new fields displayed in the suggestion box. As before, this worked perfectly fine:

[image]

Now the data source I'm using looks like this (again, shortened for readability):

```js
[
  {
    "ktb_be": "1213",
    "ktb_bezeichnung": "KTB Amberg-Sulzbach",
    "ba_nummer": "962100",
    "ba_name": "Amberg Oberpf.",
    "ursprungs_be": "2-008-1013",
    "ursprungs_bez": "Amberg",
    "seitenzahl": "182",
    "lon": "11.84603545968802",
    "lat": "49.454826399610624",
    "dLon": 11.84603545968802,
    "dLat": 49.454826399610624
  },
  {
    "ktb_be": "1213",
    "ktb_bezeichnung": "KTB Amberg-Sulzbach",
    "ba_nummer": "962802",
    "ba_name": "Ammerthal",
    "ursprungs_be": "2-008-1013",
    "ursprungs_bez": "Amberg",
    "seitenzahl": "8",
    "lon": "11.766274528840961",
    "lat": "49.44355586068654",
    "dLon": 11.766274528840961,
    "dLat": 49.44355586068654
  }
]
```

So I went on and changed the code again to fit the data:

```js
var books = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('ktb_be'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: '../testData/ktb.json'
});

books.initialize();

$('#multiple-datasets .typeahead').typeahead({
    highlight: true
},
{
    name: 'books',
    displayKey: 'ktb_bezeichnung',
    source: books.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        header: '<h3 class="book-name">Books</h3>'
    }
});
```

Well, it's no surprise that this didn't work, otherwise I wouldn't be writing this question. Here's the result:

[image]

I can guarantee that the file `ktb.json` is where it's supposed to be.

My guess is that I'm missing something crucial, but since it worked with the other data sources and this file isn't that different structure wise, I can't make out my mistake.

So please, I appreciate every kind of help.

Cheers
– Chris

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm stupid, that's the answer.

I've got `datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('ktb_be')` written down and due to the lack of knowledge I was oblivious to the fact that it's impossible to find a string containing only letters, since the field `ktb_be` contains only numeric values.

I didn't really get that the `datumTokenizer` is the search index so to speak. Now I know. I guess.